# Microsoft Azure IoT hub (java) notifies a "Lost connection to the server. Reconnecting 0 time." after sending a message

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I use the IoT Hub Java library to send messages between my devices and Microsoft Azure.

To connect I call

```
client = new DeviceClient(connString, protocol);
client.open();
```

And then, to send a message I call

```
client.sendEventAsync(message, callback, lockobj);
```

Then, my `callback` function is called when the message is sent.

However, and here is the problem, after calling `sendEventAsync` on my terminal appears infinitly the message `Lost connection to the server. Reconnecting 0 time.`

I've tried to close the connection after send the message and reopen it each time, but I think it's worst and the problem persists. Moreover, I've executed the test sample given by Azure (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-java/archive/master.zip) and I have the same problem.

So my question is, is there a problem with the library (since the problem is present even with its code)? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: today I was testing the same code as yesterday and everything worked well. So I have logged in Azure and I found this error message:

> There was an error querying devices: Forbidden:{ "Message": "ErrorCode:IotHubQuotaExceeded;Total number of messages on IotHub '[..]' exceeded the allocated quota. Max allowed message count : '8000', current message count : '20107'. Send and Receive operations are blocked for this hub until the next UTC day. Consider increasing the units for this hub to increase the quota.", "ExceptionMessage": "Tracking ID:[..]-TimeStamp:10/17/2018 08:48:37" }.

So that, the problem was that I exeeded the messages quota. However, yesterday I was confused because Azure responded me with the message "OK_EMPTY" that means that everything is ok...